# How to generate a random number to 2dp

Tags: python, decimal, rounding

I am trying to work on a random number generator which produces a random number which is to 2dp regardless of whether it needs to be. eg. 2.10 is 2.10 not 2.1, 3 = 3.00

```
import random

temp_var_4_int = random.randint(2,5) + round(random.random(),2)

print (temp_var_4_int)
```

It should randomize a number between 2 and 5 and then add a decimal to it which is rounded to 2 decimal places but I keep getting answers such as:

1.2700000000000002  instead of 1.27

I'm not sure why it's throwing this anomaly at me.

Comment: To understand why you're seeing things like `1.2700000000000002`, see: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/588004/is-floating-point-math-broken

Answer (score 0, accepted):

assuming you want your numbers in `[0, 10]` you could just do this:

```
from random import uniform

r = round(uniform(0, 10), 2)
print(f"{r:3.2f}")
```

if `r = 2.1` the format string will represent it as `"2.10"`; but for all mathematical purposes the trailing zero has no effect.

Answer (score 0):

```
import random
print("Printing random float number with two decimal places is ",
      round(random.random(), 2))
print("Random float number between 2.5 and 22.5 with two decimal places is ",
      round(random.uniform(2.5,22.5), 2))
```

Comment: While this code may answer the question, providing additional context regarding why and/or how this code answers the question improves its long-term value.

Answer (score 0):

Try to use string formatting:

```py
from random import randint, random

temp_var_4_int = round(randint(2,5) + random(), 2)

print(temp_var_4_int)
print(f"{temp_var_4_int:.2f}")
```

That would output something like:

```
2.1
2.10
```

Please note that f-strings works on Python 3.6+

Comment: That's okay but i need it kept as a number not a string as I need to do some maths with the variable

Comment: @JamesNovis if you want to show the number formatted it has to be a string especially in cases like the one I showed

Answer (score 0):

You can format the float with two digits like:

```
import random

temp_var_4_int = random.randint(2,5) + round(random.random(),2)
temp_var_4_int = '%.2f' % (temp_var_4_int)
print(temp_var_4_int)
```

According to this [Q&A](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/588004/is-floating-point-math-broken)

```
(0.1+.02)
```

will return

```
0.12000000000000001
```

and

```
'%.2f' % (0.1+.02)
```

will return

```
'0.12'
```

Try it if you please and let me know, is another example of the same issue

Comment: when i do this it is still returing a decimal such as 1.0499999999999998

Comment: @JamesNovis which version of python are you using?